# Behaviour of $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Problem : Consider the function $f(x) = x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$. A priori this function is defined for $x\neq 0$. Show that setting $f(0) = 0$ turns $f$ into a function that is differentiable everywhere.

I've no idea where to start or how to go about tackling this problem at all.

My current idea is to prove that as $x$ tends to $0$, the limit of the function $= 0$, but after this I do not know how to continue.

I've also tried looking at it with the Taylor's Theorem but I do not know how to start off with this as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Peter That won't work, since the derivative for $x \ne 0$ contains a term $- \cos(1/x)$, which has no limit for $x \to 0$.

Comment: For a graphical visualization of what is going on, see [this web page](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~frank.sottile/teaching/01S/xsin1x.html).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thanks man, helped me understand the problem a little more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For $x \ne 0$, you can simply use the standard rules of computing derivatives. For $x = 0$, use the definition of the derivative i.e.
$$
\lim_{a \to 0} \frac{f(a) - f(0)}{a - 0}.
$$

Comment: It is a little confusing to use $x$ for $\Delta x$ (or $h$) after you have said "For $x=0$.  Just sayin'.

Comment: So basically, I'm trying to show that if the derivative when x=0 exists by setting f(0) = 0 and substituting this into the definition of the derivative, it means that the function would be differentiable everywhere since it is already differentiable for all x not 0?

Comment: @Cedron Dawg You're right, I will change the notation.

Comment: @Wei Xiong Yeo Indeed, that is what you are trying to show. This function is the 'standard' example of a function that is differentiable everywhere, but does not have a continuous derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Compute $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$ and let $$x_0=0$$
and we get $$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\frac{h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h})}{h}=h\sin(\frac{1}{h})$$ and $$|h\sin(\frac{1}{h})|\le |h|$$ and this tends to $0$ for $h$ tends to $0$

Comment: I have no idea why somebody down voted this, so I upvoted it.  I think you should have included "Now let $x_0=0$", or an equivalent statement.

Comment: So basically, I'm trying to show that if the derivative when x=0 exists by setting f(0) = 0 and substituting this into the definition of the derivative, it means that the function would be differentiable everywhere since it is already differentiable for all x not 0?

Comment: I have added some lines for you!